Trouble connecting i2c devices using pi pico
I have tried for weeks now to connect literally any i2c device to a pi pico. I tried at first to use vl53lcx breakout board (https://www.dfrobot.com/product-2256.html). I connected it with jumper wires to the default I2C bus 0 pins. The i2c scanner detected nothing. I tried fiddling with this set up more to no avail. I brought a different vl53l0x breakout board (https://www.adafruit.com/product/3317). It still did not work, but I found out that if I ran i2c.scan() on a loop, it would detect it the moment it was disconnected, but it would print all 112 i2c addresses it scanned. Trying to use a driver to read distance resulted in EIO Error 5. Finally, I tried connecting an HC-SR04 sensor. Once again, i2c.scan() returned all possible addresses. However, it was actually possible to read a distance from it without an error by connecting it to VBUS power.
Going back to the 3.3V peripherals, I tried using pull up resistors on the data lines (even though the breakout boards should not need them) and using bus 1 pins. Finally, I went and brought a new pi pico 2 and tried everything above again with the same results. I used MicroPython for all of this and also different i2c scanner programs to test just in case they were faulty.
I can attach pictures of my setup if needed.
